# MySql Update Query to insert JSON values

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, laravel

In MySql I have two tables: `staff` and `certifications`.  There is a one-to-many relationship where `staff.pk` = `certifications.fk`.

For each staff member, I need to insert their multiple `certifications.name` values into a JSON column in the `staff` table.

I also need to be able to read this as an array cast in a Laravel - does that mean it needs to be a JSON array, rather than a JSON object?

UPDATE:

I need to do this as a batch process, since I have many thousands of records to process.  That's why I am concencentrating on the raw SQL.  Instantiating Eloquent models would not work from a performance perspective.

Comment: May be this could helps: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: you have already one to many relationship between `staff` and `certifications` then why do you want to store certifications in staff table ?

Comment: @rkj, I need to do the extraction because I am creating a temporary data cache from dozens of tables and passing it to a front-end app.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Accessors & Mutators

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Staff extends Model
{
    //assuming you have certificates column in staff table to store json data

    public function setCertificatesAttribute($certificates)
    {
        $this->attributes['certificates'] = json_encode($certificates);
    }

    public function getCertificatesAttribute()
    {
        if($certificates != null){
           return json_decode($certificates, true); //force to array
        }

        return []; //default empty array
    }
}
```

> Now if you create or update staff

```
Staff::create([
     'name' => 'Staff1',
     'certificates' => ['certificate1', 'certificate2'] 
]);
```

Then it will automatically saved as a json data in your staff table. And when you fetch data using `$staff->certificates` then it will return you array.

hope it may solve your problem

Comment: See UPDATE in the OP

Comment: @KimPrince can't you use `Staff::insert($staffs);` or `DB::table('staffs')->insert($staffs);` for batch operations